# SpreadsheetView Error - controlsfx

Tags: java

I used spreadsheet view of controlsfx 8.0.6U25  with earlier jdk for my work and it worked good. Recently I updated to JDK 8U40 and controlsfx 8.20.8. Sadly, the spreadsheet view won't load. I get error in my IDE anytime I run the same project. Please, has anyone faced the same problem? What is the solution? Thank you.

Please find the error I get below. I made no changes before the update.

```
Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown       Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$71/1915503092.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationError: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.SelectedCellsMap
    at impl.org.controlsfx.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetViewSelectionModel.<init>(SpreadsheetViewSelectionModel.java:198)
    at org.controlsfx.control.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetView.<init>(SpreadsheetView.java:395)
    at myStudentAssessNew.StudentAsessment$8.<init>(StudentAsessment.java:920)
    at myStudentAssessNew.StudentAsessment.addhboxCenter(StudentAsessment.java:920)
    at myStudentAssessNew.StudentAsessment.start(StudentAsessment.java:353)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$92/717936956.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1232900564.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown  Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
    Exception running application myStudentAssessNew.StudentAsessment
```

Comment: Can you post the error here? Did you make any other changes beside the update?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution rather looks simple. Since controlsfx project has not yet been updated to meet JDK 8u40 and above as at now, I just reinstalled the previous jdk (JDK 8u25) and I am okay now.